# how to connect to a web service from windows mobile(when running emulator)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, windows-mobile

I have as asp.net webserver that I hosted and I went to my mobile application I am building and made a web reference to it.

So it finds it and stuff and now I can access the web methods because of the wsdl generated. However when it tries to connect I get this:

Could not establish connection to network.

So do I have to enable something to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this article. It explains how to setup your mobile device for internet connectivity.

[Windows Mobile Emulator and Internet Connectivity](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/Programming/Handhelds_-_PDAs/Windows_Mobile/Windows-Mobile-Emulator-and-Internet-Connectivity.html)

It's been awhile since i have had to do this. Perhaps it is as easy as Matt has suggested, I can remember having a hard time making this work with Windows Vista, Visual Studio 2005 and the Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC Emulator. I've found a couple more articles, hope this helps.

[HOWTO: Configure Network in Windows Mobile / PocketPC Device Emulator](http://blog.rebex.net/news/archive/2009/01/28/howto-configuring-network-in-windows-mobile-pocketpc-device-emulator.aspx)
[Making Emulator to connect to the Network](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsdteam/archive/2005/10/07/478295.aspx)

Comment: Hmm when I try to setup the network card it keeps wanting me to install virutal pc 2007. The thing is it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have used web services and rest based services via webrequests on the emulator without needing to configure the NE2000 adapters.

Change activesync or WMDC to connect using DMA (in wmdc: mobile device settings | connection settings, then set 'allow connections to one of the following' to DMA)

Then in VS2008, under tools select device emulator manager, and pick the emulator that is running, right click on it and select cradle, this should connect activesync/wmdc to the emulator and provide a network connection that is sufficient to communicate over http with web services.